# Submiting and Validate App in App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I need release an App in **iPhone 4 support only**

I can submit if a have a this warning?

```
A launch image named "Default-568h@2x.png" is required to run at native resolution on Retina 4-inch devices.  Would you like Xcode to add this image for you?
```

Is there a possibility to reject it?

What I can do? thanks!!

Comment: I dont get it that why wont you add this image to your project. It will take only 1 minute. Just open your launch image in an adobe illustrator and changed its resolution.

Comment: It's not that simple. Once added, the rest of the app needs to be thoroughly tested to be sure it looks OK on both 3.5" and 4" displays.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, either.

Comment: Its a launch image not a new class. I doubt that testing a launch image takes the same time as testing a new functionality in the code.

Comment: @azmuhak But it is a special launch image that actually has a huge effect on how the app looks on certain devices. So yes, it requires that every screen in the app be reviewed on relevant devices to be sure it still looks OK.

Comment: Think about why your app is only relevant to iPhone 4 users - it will get downloaded on other devices as well. If it doesn't make sense on other devices, show a meaningful message there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple requires full support for the 4" screens of the new iPhones and iPod touches. There is not workaround. Apple will reject your app if you don't support the 4" screens. You must also fully support retina displays.

Answer (score 0):

May 1st onwards apple start rejecting apps which are not supporting iPhone5 and also rejecting the apps which are referring UDID. So you cannot upload the binary without adding the default-568@2x.png image.